# Select rows by date within interval in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, posix, overlap

I would like to select the observations in a data table that fall within intervals of time specified in a second data table - the intervals are periods of time when observations are made from 2 platforms concurrently.

The first data table looks something like this.  It is a bunch of animal sightings.

```
obs = data.table(sighting = as.POSIXct(c("2018-08-12 16:30:00", "2018-08-12 16:35:00", "2018-08-12 16:38:00", "2107-08-13 15:13:00", "2107-08-13 16:13:00", "2017-08-14 11:12:13"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "America/Halifax"), encounter = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "3", "4"), what = c("frog", "frog", "toad", "bird", "goat","bird"))
```

Observations were made from 2 platforms.

```
platformA = data.table(station = "A", on.effort = as.POSIXct(c("2018-08-12 16:00:00", "2018-08-12 17:35:00","2017-08-14 11:00:13", "2018-08-15 17:35:00"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "America/Halifax"), off.effort = as.POSIXct(c("2018-08-12 16:36:00", "2018-08-12 18:35:00","2017-08-14 12:12:13", "2018-08-15 18:35:00"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "America/Halifax"))

platformB = data.table(station = "B", on.effort = as.POSIXct(c("2018-08-12 16:15:00", "2018-08-12 17:40:00", "2018-08-13 17:40:00","2017-08-14 11:05:13"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "America/Halifax"), off.effort = as.POSIXct(c("2018-08-12 16:40:00", "2018-08-13 17:45:00", "2018-08-12 18:20:00","2017-08-14 12:30:13"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = "America/Halifax"))
```

I first calculated intervals for each platform, and then intersected the intervals to find out when observations were made concurrently.

```
setkey(platformA, on.effort, off.effort)
setkey(platformB, on.effort, off.effort)

common = foverlaps(platformA, platformB,type="any",nomatch=0)

common$x = intersect(interval(common$on.effort, common$off.effort), 
                     interval(common$i.on.effort, common$i.off.effort))
```

I'd like to end up with a table that is a subset of "obs" and contains only the rows covered by the intervals in "common$x".  I had hoped to use foverlaps to find the rows in the intersected intervals, and created "point" intervals for my sightings with

```
obs[, sighting2 := sighting]
```

But foverlaps wants the "start" and "end" of each interval in separate columns, which is not how the intervals are stored in common$x.

I would like my output to look like this

```
           sighting encounter what
2018-08-12 16:30:00         1 frog
2018-08-12 16:35:00         1 frog
2017-08-14 11:12:13         4 bird
```

I'd appreciate any tips.  Perhaps I could have been more efficient earlier on?
Thanks.

Comment: Can you be a little more clear on what you're hoping your output will look like? Do you want all the rows from `obs` where the `sighting` time is within an interval of time that intersects observation times in both `platformA` and `platformB`? Or do you want the subset of `obs` where the `sighting` time is in between `on.effort` and `off.effort` of either `platformA` or `platformB`?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I would like the rows in obs where sighting time is within the interval that intersects observation times in both platforms.

Comment: Please edit your question and show the desired output. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work even if you have varying observation numbers between the platforms. Using your `obs`, `platformA`, and `platformB` data as above, make intervals for both platforms more or less as you did above in `common`:

```
common = intersect(interval(platformA$on.effort, platformA$off.effort), 
                   interval(platformB$on.effort, platformB$off.effort))
```

You should be able to use `%within%` to check if there are any cases where the sighting falls within the common interval:

```
obs$both.seen <- sapply(obs$sighting, function(s){
  any(s %within% common)
})
```

**OR**

```
obs[, both.seen := sapply(sighting, function(x) any(x %within% common))]
```

New `obs`:

```
> obs
              sighting encounter what both.seen
1: 2018-08-12 16:30:00         1 frog      TRUE
2: 2018-08-12 16:35:00         1 frog      TRUE
3: 2018-08-12 16:38:00         1 toad     FALSE
4: 2107-08-13 15:13:00         2 bird     FALSE
5: 2107-08-13 16:13:00         3 goat     FALSE
6: 2017-08-14 11:12:13         4 bird      TRUE
```

Subset to get to your desired output:

```
obs <- obs[both.seen == 1][, both.seen := NULL][]

> obs
              sighting encounter what
1: 2018-08-12 16:30:00         1 frog
2: 2018-08-12 16:35:00         1 frog
3: 2017-08-14 11:12:13         4 bird
```

Answer (score 0):

I *believe* this gets you what you want. It doesn't take advantage of `data.table` functions, and runs entirely on base R. I'm not sure if this will lead to performance issues in your data, but perhaps it gives a way to think about more `data.table`-esque functions.

```
library(data.table)

# Set up the data
obs = data.table(sighting = as.POSIXct(c("2018-08-12 16:30:00", 
                                         "2018-08-12 16:35:00", 
                                         "2018-08-12 16:38:00", 
                                         "2107-08-13 15:13:00", 
                                         "2107-08-13 16:13:00", 
                                         "2017-08-14 11:12:13"), 
                                       format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", 
                                       tz = "America/Halifax"), 
                 encounter = c("1", "1", "1", "2", "3", "4"), 
                 what = c("frog", "frog", "toad", "bird", "goat","bird"))

platformA = data.table(station = "A", 
                       on.effort = as.POSIXct(c("2018-08-12 16:00:00", 
                                                "2018-08-12 17:35:00",
                                                "2017-08-14 11:00:13"), 
                                              format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", 
                                              tz = "America/Halifax"), 
                       off.effort = as.POSIXct(c("2018-08-12 16:36:00", 
                                                 "2018-08-12 18:35:00",
                                                 "2017-08-14 12:12:13"), 
                                               format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", 
                                               tz = "America/Halifax"))

platformB = data.table(station = "B", 
                       on.effort = as.POSIXct(c("2018-08-12 16:15:00", 
                                                "2018-08-12 17:40:00",
                                                "2017-08-14 11:05:13"), 
                                              format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", 
                                              tz = "America/Halifax"), 
                       off.effort = as.POSIXct(c("2018-08-12 16:40:00", 
                                                 "2018-08-12 18:20:00",
                                                 "2017-08-14 12:30:13"), 
                                               format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", 
                                               tz = "America/Halifax"))

# Get the start and end times for each observation (note use of pmax and pmin)
starts = pmax(platformA$on.effort, platformB$on.effort)
ends = pmin(platformA$off.effort, platformB$off.effort)

# For each sighting in obs check if it falls in between any of the intervals
seen = sapply(obs$sighting, function(x) {    
    any(x >= starts & x <= ends)
})

# Subset the data
obs[seen, ]

              sighting encounter what
1: 2018-08-12 16:30:00         1 frog
2: 2018-08-12 16:35:00         1 frog
3: 2017-08-14 11:12:13         4 bird
```

The primary aspect of this solution is the assignment of `start` and `end`. Since we're looking for the intersection of time of observation on two platforms, our start time is the later time of the two (i.e. the max) and our end time in the earliest time of the two platforms (i.e. the min). By using `pmin` and `pmax`, we can take get the min and max, respectively, element wise for the vectors of time. When making the comparison in `x >= start & x <= min`, a single time `x` is compared element wise to a pair of times `start[i]` and `end[i]` thereby giving us our interval of comparison.

Comment: This solution will likely fail if the `on.effort` and/or `off.effort` variables do not match up across the two data sets. If, for example, there are observations on Platform A one day, but not on Platform B, that can throw things off.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I checked out pmax and pmin - those are new to me.  I do unfortunately have days when observations were not made on both platforms though.

Comment: Please update your question to reflect that. Your minimal, reproducible problem does not sufficiently cover your problem, and solutions are therefore likely to fail under those edge cases. And please make sure to explain how you would like those situations to be handled.

Comment: @heatherr Not really. We need to see what your data looks like if there are observations on Platform A and not on Platform B, or vice versa. As of right now, we're left to infer from your example data that `platformA` and `platformB` will always have the same number of rows, and each row in each data frame lines up with each other. If these assumptions are not correct, please change your example data to reflect that.

Comment: oh.  OK.  I get it now.  I suppose in trying to simplify my data I made it far too simple without realizing it.  will give it another shot now.  thx.